# jQuery scroll image vertically inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to make a bigger photo than the div that is containing it to auto scroll vertically.

Also found a nice jQuery plugin [jQuery simplyScroll](http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/) but i can't make it run properly.

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5Lrq9zy/).

```
(function($) {
        $(function() { //on DOM ready
            $("#scroller").simplyScroll({
                customClass: 'vert',
                orientation: 'vertical',
                auto: true,
                manualMode: 'end',
                frameRate: 8,
                speed: 5
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

It doesn't scroll to bottom. What i did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/h5Lrq9zy/2/

```
.vert .simply-scroll-clip {
    width: 400px;
}
.vert .simply-scroll-list li {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Too much hardcoded stuff within the plugin itself. A terrible plugin overall, but yes, you could modified it to be better.

Comment: Thanks very much! is there any other solution with pure jquery without loading this plugin?

Also is there any way to stop continuous scroll, so when it hit the end to go up to top?

Answer (score 2):

You specified a custom class to use as a container called `vert`.

So you need to specify CSS for that class like so:

```
.vert { 
    width: 400px; /* wider than clip for custom button pos. */
    height: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

/* Clip DIV */
.vert .simply-scroll-clip {
    width: 400px;
    height: 1000px;
}

/* Explicitly set height/width of each list item */
.vert .simply-scroll-list li {
    width: 400px;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/h5Lrq9zy/1/).

Comment: thank you mccannf! Is there any way to stop continuous scroll, so when it hit the end to go up to top?